# Firebase phone authentication split into two activities

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am doing a Phone Auth Login for android studio using Firebase, My java and XML code works for the First Activity but when I try to split it up so that it works using Second Activity it crashes.

The First Activity is for receiving the user's number and once the user has entered the number and presses "send" the user is taken to the Second Activity which validates the auth code and resends the code, I am able to get the code to be sent from the first page but when I go to the second page and enter it the app crashes. When I try to debug I get null values in both the edit text fields.

```
 public class PhoneAuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "PhoneAuthActivity";

private UserInformation mUser;
EditText  mVerificationField,mPhoneNumberField;
Button mStartButton;


private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_in2);
    mUser = new UserInformation();

    // Assign views
    mPhoneNumberField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PhoneNumber);


    mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Start_Verification);

    mStartButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {


        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);
            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                mPhoneNumberField.setError("Invalid phone number.");
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                Toast.makeText(PhoneAuthActivity.this, "Quota exceeded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }


    };


}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        startActivity(new Intent(PhoneAuthActivity.this, Name_Activity.class));
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            mVerificationField.setError("Invalid code.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}




private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    //signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
}


private void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber) {
    mUser.setPhone_num(phoneNumber);
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
}






private boolean validatePhoneNumber() {
    String phoneNumber = mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)) {
        mPhoneNumberField.setError("Invalid phone number.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.Start_Verification:
            if (!validatePhoneNumber()) {
                return;
            }


  startPhoneNumberVerification(mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString());

            startActivity(new Intent(PhoneAuthActivity.this, 
      PhoneVerAuthActivity.class));
            finish();
            break;
  }

}

 }
```

the second activity

```
 public class PhoneVerAuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "PhoneAuthActivity";


String phone;

EditText  mVerificationField,mPhoneNumberField;
Button  mVerifyButton, mResendButton;
String mVerificationId;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
private UserInformation mUser;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_in3);
    mUser = new UserInformation();

    // Assign views

    mVerificationField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumVer);


    mVerifyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVerify);
    mResendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnresend);


    mVerifyButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mResendButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    phone = mUser.getPhone_num();
    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {


        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);
            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                mPhoneNumberField.setError("Invalid phone number.");
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                Toast.makeText(PhoneVerAuthActivity.this, R.string.Quota_exceeded, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;
        }
    };


}


private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        startActivity(new Intent(PhoneVerAuthActivity.this, Name_Activity.class));
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            mVerificationField.setError(getString(R.string.Invalid_code));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}





private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
}

private void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber,
                                    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks,         // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            token);             // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
}

private boolean validatePhoneNumber() {
    String phoneNumber = mVerificationField.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)) {
        mVerificationField.setError(getString(R.string.Invalid_phonenumber));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnVerify:
            String code = mVerificationField.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(code)) {

      mVerificationField.setError(getString(R.string.cannot_be_empty));
                return;
            }

            verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(mVerificationId, code);
            break;


        case R.id.btnresend:
            resendVerificationCode(phone, mResendToken);
            break;
    }

}

}
```

UserInformation

```
public class UserInformation {

private String name;
private String phone_num;

public UserInformation()
{

}

public UserInformation (String name)
{
    this.name = name;

    //this.phone_num = phone_num
}

public String getPhone_num(){
    return phone_num;
}
public void setPhone_num(String phone_num){
    this.phone_num = phone_num;
}
public String  getName() { return name; }

public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}

}



Process: com.example.bogle.chatdemo2, PID: 32609
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbo.zzcF(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential.<init>(Unknown Source) 
 at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(Unknown Source)
 at com.example.bogle.chatdemo2.PhoneVerAuthActivity.verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(PhoneVerAuthActivity.java:127)
 at com.example.bogle.chatdemo2.PhoneVerAuthActivity.onClick(PhoneVerAuthActivity.java:181)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
 at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: post error log..

Comment: @DivyeshPatel i did

Answer (score 1):

You initiate new `mUser` object.

```
 mUser = new UserInformation();
```

Then trying to get `getPhone_num()` from it but there is no phone number in it.

```
mUser.getPhone_num();
```

You have to pass `FirebaseUser user` in intent while starting second activity and then get User object from `getIntent()`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't add that file but I created another class with user information